# Borel sets used in Model Theory

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, descriptive-set-theory

In Lemma 4.4.13 (page 161) of D.Marker- Model Theory book it is proved that  $D(F,T)$ (the set of all possible F-diagrams of models of T) is a  Borel set.

Can someone explain to me the proof given a little bit more detailed?

Comment: Is there a specific part you're having trouble with, or is it the entire proof?

Comment: I´m a little bit confused about the sets that he sais are Borel, like the $E_1$, $E_2$ etc. Also when he proved that $D \subseteq D(F,T)$.